# BroadcastReceiver before Activity onPause()?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, onpause, incoming-call

When I am on an Activity and an incoming call is coming, I would like to send a parameter from the BroadCastReceiver that receives the call to the Activity before the onPause() starts. Is it possible ? Could you suggest me an alternative ?

In my tests, the Activity.onPause() starts always before the BroadCastReceiver.

I've tried to use an internal BroadcastReceiver in my Activity and an external one but I can't achieve this.

Here is a little schema of my problem.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use TelephonyManager to listen the PhoneStateListener for linstening the phone state change ?

```
 onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
```

Callback invoked when device call state changes.

Comment: yes, I tried this, but it doesn't help. The only solution I found to fix it is using a timer delay.